# How to get target number with available numbers in Vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

With respect to all,

I try to solve, to come to a solution, but in vain. It is a quiz with 209 questions, in the future, this value may be higher, it may be lower. As for that quiz, there are points: 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4. What I need is to put 40 questions on the site out of those 209 so that the total value is 100 points. I have an object that has all those points and the number of questions with those points.

{1: 130, 2: 36, 3: 17, 4: 10, 1.5: 10, 2.5: 3, 3.5: 3}

Random questions should be taken from each of these points. I have one example of what that should look like.

8 × 4,
3 × 3.5,
9 × 3,
3 × 2.5,
4 × 2,
4 × 1.5,
9 × 1

This is just an example, so it can be now, for example, 14 that carry 3 points, and there should be a smaller number of questions that carry 1 point, etc., mostly to meet the condition that there must be 40 questions, where the total is 100 points and to take the appropriate number of questions for each of the points. For example, 5 questions that carry 3.5 points cannot be taken when only 3 are available.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: *"Thanks in advance for your help."*: hold on... We expect you to demonstrate your research in the problem, show your efforts, and attempt at solving it.

Comment: ok*, first in an object the property can't be a numbre for several reasons and have to be a string, following this example. .let obj = {"n1": 130, "n2": 36, "n3": 17, "n4": 10}

Comment: Thank you for your response. To be honest, I've been trying for almost the whole day, but I still can't get to the logic so that I can do something like this, for the program itself to take random numbers, and at the same time for the total number to be 100 points, with 40 questions, for me, really hard, I couldn't go any further so I came here. @trincot

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was not a problem for me, but thank you for sure. @marcdahan

Comment: Use a recursive algorithm with backtracking. Subract 1 from the quantity of one of the point values, subtract its point values from the total, then call the function recursively requiring 1 less question to be returned. The base case is when either all the properties are empty, the points needed are 0, or you get down to needing 1 question. In the latter case, if there are any questions with the points needed, you return it. Otherwise you back-track and try a different property in the previous call.

Comment: As you can probably tell, that's a complex, expensive search through many combinations of questions. I don't know if there are any heuristics that can improve it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and response. I will try this tomorrow in the hope that I will be able to do at least something. Once again, thank you, this will mean something to me. @Barmar